# Ajax and codeigniter framework issues

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem with AJAX and CodeIgniter, I want to get total count of users in database but there is no data found.

my controller:

```
public function TotalUsers()
        {

            if($this->input->post("action")=='GetTotalUsers')
            {
                $this->load->model("usersmodel");
                $totalcount=$this->usermodel->GetTotalUserCount();
                echo $totalcount;
            }

        }
```

my model:

```
public function GetTotalUserCount()
        {
            $query = $this->db->get("users");
            return $query->num_rows();
        }
```

My html and jquery:

```
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                        <!-- small box -->
                        <div class="small-box bg-yellow">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <h3 id="totaluser"></h3>

                                <p>Total Users</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="ion ion-person-add"></i>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        GetTotalUsersCount();

        function GetTotalUsersCount() {
            var action='GetTotalUsers';
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url()?>Users/TotalUsers",
                method:"post",
                data:{action:action},
                success:function (data) {
                    $("#totaluser").html(data)
                }
            })
        }

       })


</script>
```

Comment: Forget the AJAX first. What happens when you manually browse to `/Users/TotalUsers` ?

Comment: nothing blank page

Comment: So your AJAX isn't the problem. Fix your controller action first.

Comment: so what is controller error as attached

Comment: check your `error_log`. a blank page usually indicates an HTTP 500, which means something is broke server side.

Comment: yes  http500 found but how can i echo  $thoutput of my function GetTotalUserCount

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164841/discussion-between-ahmed-gaber-and-delboy1978uk).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be sending it encoded in JSON while the controller is expecting it serialized, although I'm not sure.

Run `var_dump()` on `$this->input->post("action")`.

If that doesn't give `GetTotalUsers`, then that's you're problem. You'll need to either set the controller to accept raw post data and decode as json, serialize the data instead of using a javascript object (JSON), or if possible, just remove the action conditional because currently it doesn't look useful as shown.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `url:` is not evaluating to the correct value. There are a couple syntax errors (missing semi-colons) too.  Try this JavaScript. Use your browser's "Developer Tools" to examine the headers to see where the post "goes" and that "action" is being posted.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    GetTotalUsersCount();
    function GetTotalUsersCount() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url("Users/TotalUsers"); ?>',
            method: "post",
            data: {action: 'GetTotalUsers'},
            success: function (data) {
                $("#totaluser").text(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I'm curious why you use ajax and don't simply determine and pass the total count to the initial loading of the view?

Answer (score 0):

1.Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (or navigate to Current Page Control > Developer > 
    Developer Tools )or( use right click on your page and then select inspect 
    element)

2.Go to "Network" tab

3.Find your ajax request in "Name Path" column

4.Click on the specific ajax link